# How do I return an array in block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, afnetworking-2

this is my code

```
+(NSArray)getItem:(NSString)searchString {
NSArray *testArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];

NSString *searchURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://server.com/item/autocomplete_item.php?term=%@", searchString];
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

[manager GET:searchURL parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
  //  NSLog(@"item response object : %@", responseObject);
    testArray = (NSArray*)responseObject;
    //[self getItemArray:(NSArray*)responseObject];
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error : %@", error);
}];

return testArray;
}
```

but I got an error said :

```
variable is not asssignable(missing_block type specifier)
```

Please someone help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `__block NSArray *testArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];` For more detail go to linked question suggested by Abizern.

Comment: @abizern:: This question is not duplicated of the one you linked to.  Op needed to use a completion block.  Not just __ as suggested.

Comment: @rptwsthi:  That would not solve the problem.  Block execution is not a synchronous operation.

Comment: I tried @rptwshi suggestion but it doesn't resolve the problem. so, what is the proper way to resolve this kind of problem?

Comment: I think you are missing something , return `NSArray` / `NSArray *` ? `+(NSArray)getItem:(NSString)searchString {`

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20947755/return-an-array-after-a-completion-block-has-finished

Comment: thank you for the link @user523234. Now I solved my problem. :)